# PHP inet_pton returning empty string... var_dump says otherwise

Tags: php, mysql, ipv6

I am trying to save an IPv6 address in a MySQL database. I am using `inet_pton` to do this. However, I have noticed that some IP's (in particular this localhost IP) are returning empty strings. Example:

```php
$ip = inet_pton('::1');
```

And if a do a `var_dump` of `$ip` it shows that it's length is 16, but nothing is being returned:

```php
var_dump($ip);
// string(16) ""
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IPv6 addresses are 128bit, which is 16 bytes/chars.  `::1` corresponds to `00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01`, so you're printing 15 null bytes and 0x01, which is not a printable character.